# CSS selector for element position within element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there is any CSS selector syntax for situation like this?

```
<a href="#">Link text <span>123</span></a>
```

vs.

```
<a href="#"><span>123</span> Link text</a>
```

I need to find out if `<span>123</span>` is before or after the `Link text`.

For now I solved it with additional span class `before|after`, but I would like to know, if it could be achieved via selector. Any ideas?

Comment: You need js for this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/880/, also whitespace counts as textnode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't distinguish these cases. According to [Structural pseudo-classes](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#structural-pseudos),

> Standalone text and other non-element nodes are not counted when
>   calculating the position of an element in the list of children of its
>   parent.